# authorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'http' when running Google Cloud SDK example

Tags: python, google-cloud-sdk

I am running the following code that was taken line for line from this google cloud sdk example.

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials as creds
crm = discovery.build(
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

operation = crm.projects().create(
body={
    'project_id': 'test-project',
}).execute()
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myUsername/src/Chess/gcp/gcp_init.py", line 5, in <module>
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
TypeError: authorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'http'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OAuth2Credentials` is a class, and `authorize` is a method defined on that class. As such, its definition is something like

```
class OAuth2Credentials:
    ...
    def authorize(self, http):
        ....
```

([source](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/oauth2client/client.html#OAuth2Credentials))

You called the instance method on the class type itself, instead of initializing the class first, so the http object you passed in became `self` inside the method.

You should instantiate a `OAuth2Credentials` object first. Then, the first argument to the method automatically becomes the class instance itself, and the http param you pass in will be interpreted correctly.

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials

creds = OAuth2Credentials(...) # refer to the documentation on how to properly initialize this class
crm = discovery.build(
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

operation = crm.projects().create(
body={
    'project_id': 'test-project',
}).execute()
```

On a related note, `oauth2client` is [deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) and you should migrate to one of the newer libraries they recommend.